# Reactsx: Array of Mui components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types

In my app, I want to render an array of `MUI` `Typography` component. Currently, I have array `states` as type array of type `any`, but this is not safe.

I tried creating the array of type, `OverridableComponent<TypographyTypeMap<{}, "span">[]` but this produced errors.

See code below:

```
const CustomTooltip = ({
    active,
    payload,
  }: TooltipProps<ValueType, NameType>) => {
    if (active && payload && payload.length) {
      let states: any = [];
      payload.forEach((state: any) => {
        states.push(
          <Typography
            key={state.dataKey}
          >
            {state.dataKey} : {state.value}
          </Typography>
        );
      }); 
    }
    return(
        {states}
    );
```

**Update:**
`let states: JSX.Element[] = [];`

seems to work with no errors, but I am unsure if this is the ideal solution.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to do

```
let states: Array<Typography> = []
```

Comment: no, I resolved the issue by doing `let states: JSX.Element[] = [];`